# HTML - how to assign a value to a div tag similar to an option tag

Tags: html

I want to give an div tag a hidden value. Can this be done like it is done with option tags?

HTML

```
        <select>
            <option value="bread">field 1</option>
            <option value="butter">field 2</option>
            <option value="milk">field 3</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `data-*` attributes (e.g. `data-food`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  id="dvTEST"> </div>
```

//using JQuery  Set value

$("#dvTEST").attr("data-value","The Value")

//using Jquery  GET value

var getValue = $("#dvTEST").attr("data-value")

Thx